# Python: format float to a minimum floating point precision if needed

Tags: python, string, printing, floating-point, decimal

Say I have two numbers `1.2` and `1.24898`, how do I format the string such that anything without sufficient precision always is fixed to two floating points (`.2f`) but anything with more than 2 will retain their floating points?

I want this to be printed as: `1.20` and `1.24898`. Is there a way of doing this via `print` formatting or a pythonic way?

Doing `print(f'{1.24898:,.2f}')` will cause it to be fixed to 2 places, but I want to retain all its precision. And similarly the same for the `1.2` i want it printed as `1.20`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose a one liner version of the previous answer

```
number=1.2
print(max('{:.2f}'.format(number),str(number),key=len))
# Ouput : 1.20
number=1.24898
print(max('{:.2f}'.format(number),str(number),key=len))
# Output : 1.24898
```

Answer (score 0):

I took some elements in a list and that list has different floating-point numbers. Checked if `str(x)[::-1].find('.')` is greater than 2. If it's greater than 2. It remains the same otherwise set two precision of that number.

```
ls = [1.2, 1.24898, 3]
for x in ls:
    if str(x)[::-1].find('.') > 2:
        print(x)
    else:
        print(f'{x:.2f}')

# Output
# 1.20
# 1.24898
# 3.00
```